# Selenium ChromeDriver gives "InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process" error

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a website with selenium chromedriver. I already added some arguments that I saw in other similar issues but it didn't solve problem. I've basically this code:

```
 String baseUrl = "https://somesite.com";
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");
 ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
 options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
 options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
 options.addArguments("--disable-software-rasterizer");
 options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
 options.addArguments("headless");
 options.addArguments("--enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers");

 driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
 driver.get(baseUrl);
```

When I run the above code, chrome opens but page doesn't change. Also it gives this output:

```
[61263:61263:0903/005049.885829:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

why is this happening?

Note: My OS is ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This error message...

```
ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

...is a common Google Chrome error when trying to run it in Linux due to Chrome’s GPU usage.

First of all, `System.setProperty()` line accepts the *key* `webdriver.chrome.driver` and the *value* of the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747). So instead of:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/google-chrome");
```

You need to:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

---

### Outro

Generally this error can be addressed by avoiding the GPU hardware acceleration with the following flags:

- *`--disable-gpu`*: Disables GPU hardware acceleration. If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch
- *`--disable-software-rasterizer`*: Disables the use of a 3D software rasterizer

Code snippet:

```
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-software-rasterizer");
```