# Electron snap app not starting on Ubuntu (in hyper-v)

Tags: ubuntu, electron, hyper-v, electron-builder

Our Electorn app works in Hyper-V Windows, but fails to start on Ubuntu (20.04 and 22.04) in Hyper-V.

It seems to be a chromium issue: i.e. the electron binary starts, the window opens, but does not show any content (remains white) and we have these errors on the console:

```
2422:0708/095320.055217:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(188)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[2461:0708/095320.661858:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[2461:0708/095321.183000:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[2441:0708/095321.666150:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(250)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.Yu1hE0 failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[2441:0708/095321.666368:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(253)] Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: Operation not permitted (1)
[2441:0708/095321.666493:FATAL:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(255)] This is frequently caused by incorrect permissions on /dev/shm.  Try 'sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm' to fix.
```

I guess the relevant issue is `Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: Operation not permitted`

- `sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm` did not fix the issue
- I think the permission are okay:

  ```bash
  $ ls -l /dev | grep shm
  drwxrwxrwt  2 root root          40 Jul  8 09:54 shm

  $sudo df -a | grep shm
  tmpfs            2009376       0   2009376   0% /dev/shm
  ```
- we use electron `18.3.4`
- the `App.Image` works (tested on Ubuntu 20.04)

Any ideas? I am not sure, if this is related to Ubuntu, snap, Hyper-V or Electron...

### Update 11.07.2022

When we start the app with `--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer` ([SO-ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037458)), then the GPU related errors:

```
Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

are gone - however, the app still does not start due to the shm issue.

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same issue, but with electron 19.